# Can't read/write to/from the atmega328p

Tags: avr, atmega, fuses, avrdude, fuse-bits

I cant communicate with the Atmega328p. I've flashed fuses low: [0x59, high: 0xD9](http://eleccelerator.com/fusecalc/fusecalc.php?chip=atmega328p&LOW=59&HIGH=D9&LOCKBIT=FF) and changed wiring. Now I've connected 16Mhz crystal to the XTAL1, XTAL2 pins, and 2x22pF to the crystal. But I can't read/write from/to the chip. How can I recover my avr? Is it possible?

My chip is Atmega328p.

Comment: Have you tried the lowest baudrate for programming?

Comment: Yes. But this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Problem was with fuses. Mentioned fuse settings require a 8Mhz crystal, not 16. So I've attachd external 8Mhz crystal, then changed fuses to use with 16Mhz.